Did Augustine suggest that the differences between Matthew and Luke's genealogies mean Joseph was adopted?
The Bible says that Joseph was not the biological father of Jesus because Jesus was conceived by the power of the Holy Spirit.
However, I have heard that Augustine may have suggested that the differences between the genealogies in Matthew's gospel and Luke's gospel led him to conclude that Joseph was adopted.
This question is helpful in explaining why the two accounts differ, but I am specifically looking for a reference to Augustine that suggests Joseph was adopted.

It can be found from St. Augustine's Harmony of the Gospels Book II, Chapter III.
Quote from Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers 1.6: Saint Augustin: Sermon on the Mount, Harmony of the Gospels, Homilies on the Gospels (1888), Philip Schaff (ed.):


Furthermore, as to those critics who find a difficulty in the circumstance that Matthew enumerates one series of ancestors,
beginning With David and travelling downwards to Joseph, while Luke
specifies a different succession, tracing it from Joseph upwards as
far as to David, they might easily perceive that Joseph may have had
two fathers,—namely, one by whom he was begotten, and a second by whom
he may have been adopted11. For it was an ancient custom also among
that people to adopt children with the view of making sons for
themselves of those whom they had not begotten. For, leaving out of
sight the fact that Pharaoh’s daughter adopted Moses (as she was a
foreigner), Jacob himself adopted his own grandsons, the sons of
Joseph, in these very intelligible terms: “Now, therefore, thy two
sons which were born unto thee before I came unto thee, are mine:
Ephraim and Manasseh shall be mine, as Reuben and Simeon: and thy
issue which thou begettest after them shall be thine.” Whence also it
came to pass that there were twelve tribes of Israel, although the
tribe of Levi was omitted, which did service in the temple; for along
with that one the whole number was thirteen, the sons of Jacob
themselves being twelve. Thus, too, we can understand how Luke, in the
genealogy contained in his Gospel, has named a father for Joseph, not
in the person of the father by whom he was begotten, but in that of
the father by whom he was adopted, tracing the list of the progenitors
upwards until David is reached. For, seeing that there is a necessity,
as both evangelists give a true narrative,—to wit, both Matthew and
Luke,—that one of them should hold by the line of the father who begat
Joseph, and the other by the line of the father who adopted him, whom
should we suppose more likely to have preserved the lineage of the
adopting father, than that evangelist who has declined to speak of
Joseph as begotten by the person whose son he has nevertheless
reported him to be? For it is more appropriate that one should have
been called the son of the man by whom he was adopted, than that he
should be said to have been begotten by the man of whose flesh he was
not descended. Now when Matthew, accordingly, used the phrases,
“Abraham begat Isaac,” “Isaac begat Jacob,” and so on, keeping
steadily by the term “begat,” until he said at the close, “and Jacob
begat Joseph,” he gave us to know with sufficient clearness, that he
had traced out the order of ancestors on to that father by whom
Joseph was not adopted, but begotten.


The Joseph he is speaking about is Joseph the husband of Mary:


But even although Luke had said that Joseph was begotten by Heli, that expression ought not to disturb us to such an extent as to lead
us to believe anything else than that by the one evangelist the father
begetting was mentioned, and by the other the father adopting. ...


In the edition cited above, within Paragraph 5 there is a footnote 11 about the adoption that Augustine mentioned on another occasion:

In the Retractations (ii. 16), Augustin alludes to this passage with
the view of correcting his statement regarding the adoption. He tells
us that, in speaking of the two several fathers whom Joseph may have
had, he should not have said that there “was one by whom Joseph was
begotten, and another by whom he may have been adopted,” but should
rather have put it thus: “one by whom he was begotten, and another
unto whom he was adopted” (alteri instead of ab altero adoptatus). And
the reason indicated for the correction is the probability that the
father who begat Joseph was the mother’s second husband, who,
according to the Levirate law, had married her on the death of his
brother without issue. [That Luke gives the lineage of Mary, who was
the daughter of Heli, has been held by many scholars. Weiss, in his
edition of Meyer’s Commentary, claims that this is the only
grammatical view: see Robinson’s Greek Harmony, rev. ed. pp. 207, 208.
Augustin passes over this solution apparently because he was more
concerned to press the priestly lineage of Mary.—R.]


@Lesley - no its the Joseph with Mary. I added the next sentence that makes that clearer as it never occurred to me he might have been speaking about a different Joseph

Thank you for the clarification in your edit.
